# Visual Studio C# Inconsistent Screen Behaviour Using Single Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a small mystery on my hands.  I have created a form that prompts the user for some input then displays a CancelOK MessageBox showing the input.  The user can enter the input either by clicking on a Submit button or by hitting the Enter key.  The trick is, if the user cancels, I want the MessageBox to close and the original text in the text field to be highlighted again.  Here is the code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsManualAdditions
{
    public partial class ManualAdditionsForm : Form
    {
        public ManualAdditionsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                additionsAction();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            additionsAction();
        }

        private void additionsAction()
        {
            DialogResult btn = MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + " additions are being added manually", "Confirm Manual Additions", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            if (btn == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hellow World!");
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
                textBox1.SelectionLength = textBox1.Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The mystery is that when I run this form two different things can happen when the additionsAction() Method is called:

1)  User enters data, hits Enter key, chooses cancel, message box disappears and original text is highlighted.

2)  User enters data, clicks the Submit button, chooses cancel, message box disappears but the original text is NOT highlighted.

But both actions call the same method, namely additionsAction(), so how can the behaviour be different?!

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is different because the action of clicking the mouse on the button removes focus from the textbox, whereas pressing a key does not.

Try adding a call to [Control.Focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) or [Control.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.select.aspx) when the DialogResult is not `OK`:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
textBox1.SelectionLength = textBox1.Text.Length;
textBox1.Focus();
// Or
textBox1.Select();
```

Answer (score 1):

When Button1 is clicked, textBox1 doesn't have the focus, so no text is selected.